# See if left mouse button is held down through Powershell?

Tags: c#, powershell

So I'm trying to make a program in Powershell and I'm trying to see if the left mouse button is held down. Right now I'm using the method to run C# code in Powershell to try and do this but I have been looking for hours to find a way to see when the left mouse button is held down anywhere on the screen on any window. I can't really show what I have tried already because I've deleted them all, sorry ;(. If anyone could help, that would be amazing.

Edit:
This was the last thing that I tried.

```
$code = @"
using System;
namespace Auto
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(){
            while (true) {
        byte[] result = BitConverter.GetBytes(GetAsyncKeyState(1));
        if (result[1] == 0x80) {
          Console.WriteLine("Left Mouse Button Down");
        }
      }
        }
    }
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -Language CSharp
iex "[Auto.Program]::Main()"
```

Comment: Your C# code is missing [a P/Invoke declaration for the `GetAsyncKeyState` WinAPI function](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetAsyncKeyState.html)

Comment: As an aside: just call `[Auto.Program]::Main()` directly - no need for `Invoke-Expression` (`iex`), which [should generally be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).

Comment: And that should be absolutely obvious by the error when trying to populate the $code variable  `The name 'GetAsyncKeyState' does not exist in the current context`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it turns out I needed to add...

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(System.Int32 vKey);
```

for GetAsyncKeyState to work and that was saying that DllImport wasn't found. I also needed to add `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;` at the top for DllImport to work as well. Now it works perfectly, thank you.